# Java couchdb4j DB connection

Tags: java, database, json, couchdb, cloudant

I'm using couchdb4j to establish a connection with couchDB. It's working fine when im connecting to my local db, this is the code for that:

```
Session LocalSession= new Session("localhost", 5984);
```

But i'm trying to get a connection with this site: stockquotetest.cloudant.com but it's not working, can anybody spot the problem?

```
Session NewSession = new Session("stockquotetest.cloudant.com/", 5984, "user", "pass");
```

i'm getting this error: INFO: basic authentication scheme selected

I also get this

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: https
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:82)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:127)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
at com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session.http(Session.java:364)
at com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session.get(Session.java:325)
at com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session.getDatabaseNames(Session.java:167)
at CouchDBTest.ConnectDB(CouchDBTest.java:41)
at Home$4.actionPerformed(Home.java:166)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

when I run this line of code:

```
        Session NewSession = new Session("https://user:pass@stockquotetest.cloudant.com/", 80, true);
```

Comment: you have to connect on port 80 (or 443 for https)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but im stil getting the same error
      Session NewSession = new Session("stackis.cloudant.com/", 443, "stackis", "cloudant");

Comment: what error? The INFO message you are talking about is not an error at all

Comment: dec 10, 2013 8:14:13 EM org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor selectAuthScheme
INFO: basic authentication scheme selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced this and ran into another issue before I got it working. First, the [6-parameter constructor for `Session`](https://github.com/mbreese/couchdb4j/blob/master/src/java/com/fourspaces/couchdb/Session.java#L96) is what you're after:

```java
public Session(String host, int port, String user, String pass, boolean usesAuth, boolean secure) {
```

In the example you gave above, this would work:

```java
new Session("stockquotetest.cloudant.com", 443, "user", "pass", true, true);
```

This is because if you don't set `secure` to true, the [URL will not be constructed with https](https://github.com/mbreese/couchdb4j/blob/master/src/java/com/fourspaces/couchdb/Session.java#L246-L253).

---

After that was working, the next error was the `Database` class [assuming that `update_seq` is an int](https://github.com/mbreese/couchdb4j/blob/master/src/java/com/fourspaces/couchdb/Database.java#L59). Cloudant will return a String `update_seq`, not an integer. I altered the field, response parsing, and getter in the `Database` class from `int` to `String` to make the code work for me.

Comment: Technically that is the *6* parameter constructor, not 5.

Answer (score 0):

try this one ... make sure you are suing coucjdb4j lib for couchdb connection.

Session studentDbSession = new Session("localhost", 5984);

Database studentCouchDb = studentDbSession.getDatabase("database_name");

Hope this will help you.